# IP Address Validation in Controller in Laravel 5

Tags: validation, laravel-5, ip-address

I am trying to find a method to validate IP Address before submitting this to my database, I have tried a lot of Google Search but unable to do this in my Laravel Controller. Can you please help? Appreciated

Comment: Share what you have found, what you have tried. And read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: // sanitized ip address
    $clean_ip_address = addslashes(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($iplive))));
    // the regular expression for valid ip addresses
    $reg_ex = '/^((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))*$/';
   
   // test input against the regular expression
     if (preg_match($reg_ex, $clean_ip_address)) { 
       $iplive = $iplive;; // it's a valid ip address
     }
   else {
       $iplive = "IP String is Invalid";
   }

Comment: Sorry I have no option to update my Question, but the above code is something that I am using in custom to validate my IP address but still searching for laravel built in validation. Thanks

Comment: How about `Validator::make(['ip' => $iplive], ['ip' => 'required|ip']);` ? Laravel has a built-in IP validation rule.

Comment: It seems , it working, I have added use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator; in Controller, does its required only or i also need something else for future?

Comment: No, you actually don't need the *required* rule there.

Comment: ok and thank you so much for the help. I have one last question, can I use this in Route File ?

Comment: Sure you can. It's not different than using in controllers.

Comment: Did you try the Laravel documentation…? https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-ip

Answer (score 13):

Use inside your controller. Import validator class's namespace and try it for validating IP (IP4/ IP6) address. `Laravel 5` and `Laravel 5.X`

```
public function update(Request $request) 
{
   $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'ip_address' => 'required|ip'
    ]);
}

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return "Invalid IP address!"
}
```

If you want to validate IP4 and IP6 respectively, then use following code.

```
'ip_address' => 'required|ipv4'

'ip_address' => 'required|ipv6'
```

Happy Coding !!!

Comment: This is a proper answer as `required|ipv4` was exactly I was looking for. Using Laravel 5.6 here.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it either inside the controller itself:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    // Get the current users IP address and add it to the request
    $request->merge(['ip_address' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']]);

    // Validate the IP address contained inside the request
    $this->validate($request, [
        'ip_address' => 'required|ip'
    ]);
}
```

The `$request->merge()` method will allow you to add items to the form request, and then you can just make a simple validate request on the IP only.

Alternatively, you could move all this to it's own Request class and inject that into the method.

Comment: I would use `$request->ip()` here instead of `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to make it more readable and prevent the use of super global variable.

Answer (score 0):

```php
// If system bypas on proxy (E.g load balancer, nginx proxy, etc)
// X-FORWARDED-FOR
$remoteAddress = $request->header('X-FORWARDED-FOR');
// or 
$remoteAddress = $request->header('X-FORWARDED-FOR') ?? $request->header('REMOTE-ADDR');

// Default remote address
// REMOTE-ADDR
$remoteAddress = $request->header('REMOTE-ADDR');

$allowedAddresses = [
    '192.168.1.50',
    '192.17.1.50/24',
    '10.17.0.0/16',
];

if (!\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\IpUtils::checkIp($remoteAddress, $allowedAddresses)) {
    abort(403); // By security proposes, I use 404 (prevent bots)
}

// All right. Is allowed
```